# How to use quantifier in regular expressions?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to enter a string without any numbers with a minimum of 4 characters
but when I enter a string without numbers it still gives me an error and I don't know why.

#### Attempt

```
string pattern = "^[a-zA-Z]{4}$";
            Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
            string name = "evvFss";
            if(!rgx.IsMatch(name))
            {
              throw new Exception("error");
            }
            else
            {
               Console.WriteLine("correct");
            }
```

It shouldn't give an error because the string doesn't contain any numbers.

Comment: fwiw for regex questions like this you should be using http://regex101.com and testing it before posting

Comment: Have you been able to determine what error you're getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{4}` tells it to match exactly that many characters, not at least that many.

Use `{4,}` to make it a minimum of four characters.

Comment: @younessouachao You can click the check mark to the left of the answer to mark it as "accepted": See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work